# How can i show categories with cascader(ant.design)?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am developing a react application using Ant design. There are categories and there are categories under categories such as electronics-computer-keyboard. I am preparing a rearrangement page for these categories. If I want to edit the computer category, I can get the electronic information as the parent category information. However, When I want to edit the keyboard category, instead of the computer as the upper category information, the id information of the computer category is displayed.

```
function CategoryEdit() {
const { userInfo } = useSelector(state => state.auth);
const { categoryInfo } = useSelector(state => state.category);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const params = useParams();
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [err, seterr] = useState('');
const [form] = Form.useForm();
const fetchData = async () => {
await dispatch(getCategoryById(params))
setLoading(false);
}

  useEffect(() => {
  const fetchCategories = async () => {
  const request = {
    Id: userInfo.clientId
  };
  const response = await dispatch(getCategories(request));
  const data = response.payload;
  const cascaderData = transformCategories(data);
  setCategories(cascaderData);
 };
fetchCategories();
   }, []);
  const transformCategories = (data, parentId = null) => {
   if (!data) {
     return [];
   }

const children = data.filter((category) => category.parentCategoryId === parentId);
if (!children || children.length === 0) {
  return [];
}

const cascaderData = children.map((category) => {
  const parentCategory = data.find((c) => c.id === category.parentCategoryId);
  console.log(parentCategory);
  const cascaderItem = {
    value: category.id,
    label: category.name,
    parentId: category.parentCategoryId,
    parentLabel: parentCategory ? parentCategory.name : null,
  };
  const nestedChildren = transformCategories(data, category.id);
  if (nestedChildren.length > 0) {
    cascaderItem.children = nestedChildren;
  }

  return cascaderItem;
});

return cascaderData;
};
 useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
  document.title = 'Kategori Değiştir';
 }, []);

<Form
      form={form}
      {...layout}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
      initialValues={{
        Name: categoryInfo.name, EmailHost: categoryInfo.emailHost, EmailPort: categoryInfo.emailPort,
        EmailUsername: categoryInfo.emailUsername, EmailPassword: categoryInfo.emailPassword,
        EmailFrom: categoryInfo.emailFrom, EmailDisplay: categoryInfo.emailDisplay,
        ParentCategoryId: categoryInfo.parentCategoryId
      }}>
      <FormCard
        className='card'
        extra={
          <Space>
            <FormButton icon={<ArrowLeftOutlined />} className={'button-citylist'} type={'default'} link={'/category/list'} text={'Geri'} />
            <FormButton icon={<CheckOutlined />} className={'button-citylist'} type={'primary'} htmlType={'submit'} text={"Kaydet"} />
          </Space>
        }
        bordered={false}>
        {err && (
          <ErrorAlert error={err} type={"error"} />
        )}
        <Row>
          <Col span={12}>
            <Form.Item name="ParentCategoryId" label="Üst Kategori" wrapperCol={{ span: 17, }}>
              <Cascader
                changeOnSelect
                options={categories || []}
                placeholder="Kategori seçin"
                fieldNames={{ label: 'label', value: 'value', children: 'children' }}
              />
            </Form.Item>
            <InputDisableText labelCol={7} label={"Kategori İsmi"} name={"Name"} rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Kategori İsmi bilgisi gereklidir.' }]} />
            <InputDisableText labelCol={7} label={"E-posta Sunucusu"} name={"EmailHost"} />
            <InputDisableText labelCol={7} label={"E-posta Port"} name={"EmailPort"} rules={[{ pattern: /^[0-9]*$/, message: 'Geçerli bir port numarası giriniz.', }
            ]} />
            <Form.Item name="EmailSsl" wrapperCol={{ offset: 7, span: 16 }}>
              <Checkbox
                checked={componentDisabled}
                onChange={handleChange}
              >SSL ile bağlan
              </Checkbox>
            </Form.Item>
            <InputDisableText labelCol={7} label={"Kullanıcı Adı"} name={"EmailUsername"} />
            <InputDisableText labelCol={7} label={"Şifre"} name={"EmailPassword"} rules={[{ min: 6, message: "Şifre bilgisi en az 6 karakter olmalıdır." }]}
              type={"password"} />
            <InputDisableText labelCol={7} label={"Gönderen E-posta"} name={"EmailFrom"} />
            <InputDisableText labelCol={7} label={"Gönderen Görünecek Ad"} name={"EmailDisplay"} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </FormCard>
    </Form>
```

[image: The entire hierarchical structure]
[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]